# Problem SSH from Ubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, connection

I am trying to connect to an Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS from an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS and I get the following SSH log:

```
ssh -vvv -p portno theuser@myserver.mydomain.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "myserver.mydomain.com" port portno
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserver.mydomain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx] port portno.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to myserver.mydomain.com:portno as 'theuser'
debug3: put_host_port: [myserver.mydomain.com]:portno
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [myserver.mydomain.com]:portno
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx port portno
```

On the server side I get the following log in the auth.log

```
Did not receive identification string from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I get the same message for two difference users

I have tried two other Ubuntu and windows machines from the same source network to connect to the server and it was successful!

When I establish a vpn connection from my Desktop Ubuntu to a third server and try to connect to my server using SSH, it is successful!

It was working fine before this and I'm wondering what has changed on the computer that causes this!

Comment: Have you tried already reconfiguring your ssh on your host? Only you can tell us what changed on the host, did you install something? Did you update something? Did you create new keys? Did you clone the machine on which you try it?

Comment: post the full log.

Comment: >Jakuje full log added

>Ziazis how to reconfigure ssh on my host? I've removed and installed again the openssh. I do update everything almost everyday.
There was no cloning.
After the problem show up, I regenerated the keys on the server to see if the problem is solved.